# Which of these basic quantified statements are true?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

I have to see if the following statements are true.

A) $\forall x \in \mathbb Z, x^2 \le 1000 $

If it not true than find an counterexample

B) $\exists x \in \mathbb R,$  such that $x^2 \lt 1 $

If it is true, than find an example.

--

For A) I think its not true because what if x = 1001. But what would be the counter example?

For B) I think its true because it has to be true for atleast once. So if I put x = -1, its true.

If I'm wrong please let me know.

Comment: For A) you seem to have the right idea. However you don't seem to understand what a counter-example is. Do you? Regarding B), $\underbrace{(-1)^2}_{=1}<1$ doesn't work.

Comment: I thought when it says counter-example, it means like find a statement that works or something like that, and oops x = 0 should work?

Comment: A counter example is an example to prove that a universal statement is false. The given statement, $\forall x\in \mathbb Z\left(x^2\leq 1000\right)$, is a universal statement and you correctly said it is false. So you just need to find an example of $x$ in the given universe ($\mathbb Z$) that makes the statement $x^2\leq 1000$ false. You have done this,

Comment: oh okay I got it, thanks alot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, A) is false. You've just given us a counterexample ($x = 1001$).

Yes, B) is true, but your example does not work ($(-1)^2 = 1 \geq 1$).

Comment: Didn't know what it meant by counter example but thank you. and oops I read it as less than and equal to 1. x=0 should work. Thanks~!